# How can I view the print modal in chrome with Karate UI

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I have  case where I need to click on a print icon in an application and that pops up a print window in Chrome.

I would like to confirm that his occured.

I have the following code

```
Scenario:
      Given driver 'appURL'
      * waitFor('#printIcon')
      And click('#printIcon')
      Then match text('.action-button') contains 'Save'
```

However it doesn't take the print page elements and I get a failure.

Is there a way to switch to the print modal?

Thank you,

Comment: marked them all as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the print dialog may be OS specific, which means it is not controllable by the test-automation.  Sorry, this is a case where I'd like the community to do the research and figure out what the options are.

Note that you can do some research into [Karate Robot](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot) if that helps :)

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look, I don't think the print modal is OS specific as the behaviour is the same in linux and windows in Chrome, but i'll play around with Karate Robot and see if I can make it work.